# pyelasticsearch bulk ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I'm new in Python and Elasticsearch.
I'm trying to write code to insert documents in Elassticsearch using bulk. It is based on this description:
http://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearch.bulk

My code:

```
>>> from pyelasticsearch import ElasticSearch
>>> es = ElasticSearch()
>>> es.bulk([es.index_op(doc={'id': 1, 'color': 'red'}), es.index_op(doc={'id': 2, 'color': 'green'})], doc_type='test10', index='test10')
```

Python returns this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/fikfok/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 93, in decorate
    return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fikfok/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 447, in bulk
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/home/fikfok/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 276, in send_request
    body=body)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But it inserts these documents into Elasticsearch.

What I use:

```
Linux Mint 18.1
Elasticsearch 5.5.0 (engine)
virtualenv
Python 3.5.2
pyelasticsearch 1.4
elasticsearch 5.4.0 (package in virtual env "test_env")
```

Please tell me where I'm wrong and how to fix the error. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue?